# Chess variants-Anyone recall the name for one that has a "superpiece" with the movements of the queen and knight?

Tags: chess-variants, unorthodox-pieces, identify-this

What is the name of the chess piece in a variant game where there is a piece that moves like the queen AND a knight?

Is there a name for this variant?

Comment: This links to two games involving this superpiece. The games can be played against computer.: https://www.facebook.com/groups/InteractiveChessPuzzles/permalink/2829670757095617/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia variants page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_variants), there does not seem to be a variant with a specific name, but there are several variants that use the queen-knight hybrid, which is [called an Amazon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_(chess)) (appropriate name, and combines rook+bishop+knight movement abilities). So maybe just "Amazon chess" would make sense.

The Amazon is used in the following variants (copied from the Wikipedia page above):

1. **Maharajah and the Sepoys**: Black has a complete army, and White only one piece: the maharajah (Amazon).
2. **Musketeer Chess**: A commercial variant, inspired from Seirawan Chess. This variant introduces 10 fairy pieces: archbishop, chancellor, hawk (different rules from Seirawan Chess), elephant (different rules from Seirawan Chess), leopard, cannon (different from Xiangqi), unicorn, fortress, spider, and amazon (also called dragon in this game). Players have a choice of 2 pieces among the 10 possible and method used to introduce them during the game.
3. **Wolf Chess**: On an 8×10 board, with fairy pieces wolf (empress), fox (princess), nightrider, sergeant (almost a Berolina pawn), and elephant (amazon). By Arno von Wilpert (1943).

There are also the following hybrid pieces:

1. [Empress (rook+knight)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empress_(chess))
2. [Princess (knight+bishop)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_(chess))
3. The traditional Queen (rook+bishop)

Comment: A few more historical variants using the piece appear on the ChessVariants.com page for the piece: https://www.chessvariants.com/piececlopedia.dir/amazon.html

Answer (score 1):

The Chess variants site has introduced tags recently and you can find some games with the tag [Piece:Amazon](https://www.chessvariants.com/tag/Piece%3AAmazon). As of the day of writing this answer, the tagging is not yet comprehensive and a lot of games featuring the Amazon are still missed by this but I expect things to improve over time.

In addition, there is a list of games with the Amazon in the [Piececlopedia entry Amazon](https://www.chessvariants.com/piececlopedia.dir/amazon.html) on the same site.